# flutter corner radius with transparent background

Tags: dart, flutter

Below is my code which I expect to render a round-corner container with a transparent background.

```
return new Container(
                //padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                height: 800.0,
                //color: const Color(0xffDC1C17),
                //color: const Color(0xffFFAB91),
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.green, //new Color.fromRGBO(255, 0, 0, 0.0),
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft:  const  Radius.circular(40.0),
                    topRight: const  Radius.circular(40.0))
                ),
                child:  new Container(
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft:  const  Radius.circular(40.0),
                            topRight: const  Radius.circular(40.0))
                    ),
                  child: new Center(
                    child: new Text("Hi modal sheet"),
                  )

              ),
```

However this is what it renders, it renders a white container (expected transparent) with a round corner radius. Any help?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 172):

If you wrap your `Container` with rounded corners inside of a parent with the background color set to `Colors.transparent` I think that does what you're looking for. If you're using a `Scaffold` the default background color is white. Change that to `Colors.transparent` if that achieves what you want.

```
        new Container(
          height: 300.0,
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: new Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.green,
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                topRight: const Radius.circular(40.0),
              )
            ),
            child: new Center(
            child: new Text("Hi modal sheet"),
           )
         ),
        ),
```

Comment: If I use image in **SliverAppBar**, then how to do that?

Comment: you can use SliverFillRemaining(child: aboveCode)

Answer (score 61):

If you want to round corners with transparent background, the best approach is using ClipRRect.

```
return ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
  child: Container(
    height: 800.0,
    width: double.infinity,
    color: Colors.blue,
    child: Center(
      child: new Text("Hi modal sheet"),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: This works.. but at end of my container the radius os squared: https://imgur.com/a/Qb5kaVW. you can help me?

Comment: Works also with `ColorFiltered`. The `BoxDecoration` fails to cut corners if you have `ColorFilter` with `BlendMode.color`.

Comment: when used with showModalBottomSheet you have to specify the bottomSheetTheme like  @jayjw suggested

Answer (score 33):

As of May 1st 2019, use ***BottomSheetTheme***.

```
MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
      // Draw all modals with a white background and top rounded corners
      bottomSheetTheme: BottomSheetThemeData(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(10))
        )
      )
    ),
```

[Introduced](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/31318) recently, using a theme to control the sheets style should be the best route.

If you want to theme different bottom sheets differently, include a new Theme object in the appropriate subtree to override the bottom sheet theme just for that area.

If for some reason you'd still like to override the theme manually when launching a bottom sheet, **showBottomSheet** and **showModalBottomSheet** now have a **backgroundColor** parameter. Use it like this:

```
 showModalBottomSheet(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    context: context,
    builder: (c) {return NavSheet();},
  );
```

Comment: `backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,` worked for me

Comment: Thanks a lot! The second method worked here

Answer (score 16):

```
/// Create the bottom sheet UI
  Widget bottomSheetBuilder(){
    return Container(
      color: Color(0xFF737373), // This line set the transparent background
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(16.0),
                topRight: Radius.circular( 16.0)
            )
        ),
        child: Center( child: Text("Hi everyone!"),)
      ),
    );
  }
```

Call this to show the BotoomSheet with corners:

```
/// Show the bottomSheet when called
  Future _onMenuPressed() async {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (widgetBuilder) => bottomSheetBuilder()
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 16):

It's an old question. But for those who come across this question...

The white background behind the rounded corners is not actually the container. That is the canvas color of the app.

**TO FIX: Change the canvas color of your app to Colors.transparent**

Example:

```
return new MaterialApp(
  title: 'My App',
  theme: new ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.green,
    canvasColor: Colors.transparent, //----Change to this------------
    accentColor: Colors.blue,
  ),
  home: new HomeScreen(),
);
```

Comment: It does have some drawbacks. Other objects that depend on the canvas color, like the refresh icon, will have a transparent background as well, instead of white.

Comment: I would not recommend doing this. A lot of widgets rely on the canvas color and those would all then need to be set individually.

Comment: best answer, this should be the top answer.

Comment: when use this, all `canvasColor` of **flutter** `widgets` will change to `color.transparent`, please try to open drawer, what u see !

Comment: Finally! Solved my issue.

Comment: this completely changed my app to black  can't see any thing

Answer (score 10):

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('BMI CALCULATOR'),
  ),
  body: Container(
    height: 200,
    width: 170,
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Color(
        0xFF1D1E33,
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 5):

## Use transparent background color for the modalbottomsheet and give separate color for box decoration

---

```
   showModalBottomSheet(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      context: context, builder: (context) {
    return Container(

      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft:Radius.circular(40) ,
            topRight: Radius.circular(40)
        ),
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20,horizontal: 60),
      child: Settings_Form(),
    );
  });
```

Answer (score 5):

```
showModalBottomSheet(
   context: context,
   builder: (context) => Container(
            color: Color(0xff757575), //background color 
            child:  new Container(
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft:  const  Radius.circular(40.0),
                        topRight: const  Radius.circular(40.0))
                ),
              child: new Center(
                child: new Text("Hi modal sheet"),
              )

     

 ),

)
```

This is will make your container color the same as the background color. And there will be a child container of the same height-width with blue color.
This will make the corner with the same color as the background color.

Answer (score 1):

Three related  packages for covering this issue with many advanced options are:

- [sliding_up_panel](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel)
- [modal_bottom_sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet)
- [sliding_panel](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_panel)

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyApp2 extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
    return MaterialApp( 
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          elevation: 0,
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
        )
      ),
      title: 'Welcome to flutter ',
      home: HomePage()
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  int number = 0;
  void _increment(){
   setState(() {
      number ++;
   });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('MyApp2'), 
          leading: Icon(Icons.menu),
          // backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,

          ),
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(200.0),
              topRight: Radius.circular(200)
            ), 
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        )
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If both containers are siblings and the bottom container has rounded corners
and the top container is dynamic then you will have to use the stack widget

```
Stack(
 children: [
   /*your_widget_1*/,
  /*your_widget_2*/,
 ],
);
```