# how to change modal sheet top edges to circular shape not working

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to give a circular radius to my modal sheet using the shape parameter but it's not working.

I have tried giving the container inside radius decoration as well still no use.

This is what i did

```
  void modalScreen(BuildContext ctx) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(25.0)),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        context: ctx,
        builder: (ctx) {
          return Container(
            height: 600,
              child: AddEntries(entriesList, entryIn),
            );
        });
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Checkout my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53656087/9185192

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a modal bottomsheet with circular corners in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50376200/how-to-create-a-modal-bottomsheet-with-circular-corners-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is just because of child - AddEntries(entriesList, entryIn)

remove it and Add Text("DEMO") widget instead of Add Entries, it will start working.

Child is using all size available. you need to add padding in it.